# laravel query skip/take not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I've got a query:

```
$eventsList = DB::table('events')
    ->where('start', '>', Carbon::now())
    ->orWhere(function($query)
  {
      $query->where('start', '<', Carbon::now())
            ->where('end', '=', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
  })
  ->orderBy($order_by, $order)
  ->get();
```

That works fine and returns around 50 results. But I want to limit and page the returned entries, so I add a `->skip()` and `->take()` chain:

```
$eventsList = DB::table('events')
    ->where('start', '>', Carbon::now())
    ->orWhere(function($query)
  {
      $query->where('start', '<', Carbon::now())
            ->where('end', '=', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
  })
  ->orderBy($order_by, $order)
  ->skip(0)->take(10)
  ->get();
```

But now it returns nothing. What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: added result of getQueryLog():

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["query"]=>
    string(112) "select * from `events` where `start` > ? or (`start` < ? and `end` = ?) order by `start` asc limit 10 offset 0"
    ["bindings"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      object(Carbon\Carbon)#225 (3) {
        ["date"]=>
        string(19) "2014-06-27 13:31:12"
        ["timezone_type"]=>
        int(3)
        ["timezone"]=>
        string(13) "Europe/London"
      }
      [1]=>
      object(Carbon\Carbon)#228 (3) {
        ["date"]=>
        string(19) "2014-06-27 13:31:12"
        ["timezone_type"]=>
        int(3)
        ["timezone"]=>
        string(13) "Europe/London"
      }
      [2]=>
      string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    }
    ["time"]=>
    float(0.76)
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks fine, check the query with `DB::getQueryLog()` for example.

Comment: Thanks for that - I've added the results of `getQueryLog`, but I' not sure how to interpret it.

Comment: That means the query is executed as it should and the problem lies elsewhere. What result do you get exactly? It should be either an array of stdObjects or empty array.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume the following:

when you say PAGE the result - you actually mean give me 10 at a time.

If thats the case use `->take($limit)->offset($offset)` instead in order to take 10 and then your offset is your chunk

where offset = $page * 10

Now as an added thing: laravel leverage for you pagination with the function paginate(10)

http://laravel.com/docs/pagination